# Right linear context free grammar with even difference of 0's and 1's

Tags: prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg

I'm trying to write a *right linear context free grammar*, in which the difference between numbers of 0's and 1's should be even. For example:

```
010001 = 4 - 2 = 2 (even)
```

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896596/right-linear-context-free-grammar). Maybe it will help! I'm trying to write it on prolog. I did other 10 exercises but this is too difficult for me. Any ideas on how to do it?

my code

```
s --> [].
s --> [1],a.
s --> [0],b.

a --> [1],s.
a --> [0],c.

b --> [1],c.
b --> [0],s.

c --> [].
c --> [1],b.
c --> [0],a.
```

It's work for many cases but I'm not sure if it is well.

Comment: People at stackoverflow don't do homeworks. If you have a question concerning your exercise, you should show us what you've tried so far, and what isn't going as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be greatly simplified with a little math.

Let `a` be number of 0, `b` - number of 1, `n` - length of a word. We want `abs(a - b)` to be even.

Do the math:

```
a + b = n
b = n - a
a - b = a - n + a = 2*a - n
```

`2*a` is always even, so `abs(a - b)` is even iff `n` is even.

So the task is really just to check if the length of the word is even.

Solution:

```
s --> [].
s --> digit, digit, s.
digit --> [0].
digit --> [1].
```

Comment: You're right! The simplest solution is the hardest to invent.